# Dataset where words are associated to colors

Tags: data-request, language

I am looking for a dataset mapping concrete words with common colors.
The only one i've found is [this](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/color-terms-dataset/data), but it has less than 100 entries.

EDIT: example:

```
red_words_list = [ "apple", "blood", "rose", "strawberry", "cherry" ]
green_words_list = [ "grass", "tree", "forest", "clover" ]
yellow_words_list = [ "banana", "star", "sun", "desert", "lemon", "gold" ]
```

It will be used to colorize lyrics using my [audioleds.py script](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/electr/audioleds.py).

Comment: Try [wikidata](http://tinyurl.com/y9dq5e5v) -- start with the linked query and refine.

Comment: seems a good start, if you know how to select only concrete words this could be a valid answer...

Comment: There is probably a wikidata property for concreteness, but I'm too lazy to check.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you rephrase your question, google gives some good results. For example, those in marketing & branding study the association of [colors with feelings](https://www.viget.com/articles/using-word-association-to-select-brand-colors).

The article above has sources linked for everything, and depending on how wide you want to go from the literal color of the object, this could be a good direction.

Another direction could be linguistic research studies, where people associate words with colors.

---

To find this page, I had to start with a basic web search, and then remove false hits (like "Excel"). Here was the final query, maybe it helps.

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=words+that+have+a+certain+color+-excel+-Synesthesia+-highlight+-html

(so I removed results with "excel", "Synesthesia", "highlight", and "html". I think in your question, using the word "mapping" will bring up mostly technical results, such as excel)

Answer (score 1):

I won't expect a ready-made data set for these specifications.

However, it is easy create such kind of dataset yourself. You need a big corpus of English text and a Corpus Query Processor (like [cqpweb](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/cqpweb.php)). A query for red things than looks like

```
[word="red" [pos="N.*"]
```

asking for bigrammes consisting of the word "red" and a noun. Than, do a frequency breakdown to get output like this one (data are taken from the Corpus of Late Modern English CLMET):

```
Your query “[word="red"] [pos="N.*"]” returned 1,803 matches in 198 different texts (in 40,340,760 words [333 texts]; frequency: 44.69 instances per million words)
Showing frequency breakdown of words in this query, at the query node; there are 656 different types and 1,803 tokens at this concordance position.
No.     Search result   No. of occurrences  Percent
1   red hair    47  2.61%
2   red face    40  2.22%
3   red clay    35  1.94%
4   red deer    28  1.55%
5   red weed    27  1.5%
6   red brick   27  1.5%
7   red colour  26  1.44%
8   red glow    26  1.44%
9   red eyes    24  1.33%
```